# Processing: Partially blurring part of the background

Tags: processing

Some background information: This project is a simple image that at the end of the project is going to become the background of my computer screen.

I'm wanting to blur part of the background so that the part of the text is more visible. I could blur part of the image where the text is its self, but this is my last resort. I don't want to do this because, in a future project I want to actively blur the background as something moves around (I have not started this future project yet, so I can't describe that project any better).

Does anyone know how to blur a portion of the background? For this project, it needs to be roughly 400x200 pixels and be blurred 10%-15%

Comment: Is there a special reason why you don't GiMP your way out of this?

Comment: Again, last resort. I just like the challenge and as a young coder, I like working with programming languages as much as I can

Comment: Ok, you would need to post code and a specific question related to this code to get good help here. To help you to get started, I suggest that you look up [the blur function](https://processing.org/examples/blur.html) that's already in Processing. Also, and maybe more importantly, if you're confortable with working with a pixel array, the `PImage` class has the [`.loadPixels()` method which fills the `.pixels[i]` array](https://processing.org/reference/PImage_pixels.html) so you can work with them directly. The rest is a good algorithm and math.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that will do exactly that. It's static method, taking in a reference to the PApplet, so if you're working in the PDE, you can remove this parameter from the method signature. Also, with this method you specify the center of the region, not the left-upper corner (modify as you see fit).

```
public static void blur(applet p, int regionCentreX, int regionCentreY, int regionWidth, int regionHeight,
        float blurStrength) {

    PGraphics g;
    g = p.createGraphics(regionWidth, regionHeight);
    g.beginDraw();
    g.loadPixels();

    int cornerX = PApplet.constrain(regionCentreX - (regionWidth / 2), 0, p.width - regionWidth);
    int cornerY = PApplet.constrain(regionCentreY - (regionHeight / 2), 0, p.height - regionHeight);

    p.loadPixels();
    int graphicsIndex = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < regionHeight; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < regionWidth; x++) {
            g.pixels[graphicsIndex] = p.pixels[(cornerY + y) * p.width + (cornerX + x)];
            graphicsIndex++;
        }
    }
    p.updatePixels();

    g.updatePixels();
    g.filter(PConstants.BLUR, blurStrength);
    g.endDraw();
    p.image(g, cornerX, cornerY);
}
```

Example, blurStrength=5:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Michael's answer nicely encapsulates the functionality you're after.

FWIW here is a modified version of **Examples > Basic > Image > LoadDisplayImage** illustrating the blur filter:

```
/**
 * Load and Display 
 * 
 * Images can be loaded and displayed to the screen at their actual size
 * or any other size. 
 */

PImage img;  // Declare variable "a" of type PImage

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  // The image file must be in the data folder of the current sketch 
  // to load successfully
  img = loadImage("moonwalk.jpg");  // Load the image into the program  
}

void draw() {
  // take an image subsection
  PImage blurred = img.get(mouseX, mouseY, 210, 210);
  // blur that section
  blurred.filter(BLUR, 8);

  // Displays the image at its actual size at point (0,0)
  image(img, 0, 0);
  // render blurred subsection (in the same spot)
  image(blurred, mouseX, mouseY);
}
```

[image: Moon landing image with the lunar module blurred as an example of using the blur filter on a subsection of an image]

Bare in mind on large images with a large blur amount this can get slow.

Should you need a faster approach you can look at fragment shaders, implemented in Processing as [PShader](https://processing.org/tutorials/pshader/): **Examples > Topcs > Shaders > BlurFilter** should be a good starting point.